# How to compile php-memcached at PHP7.1 correct?

Tags: linux, memcached, php-7.1, debian-jessie, libmemcached

I would like installed PHP Memcached on my Operating System. You can find more informations about my system on following facts.

- Operating system: Debian 8 (Jessie)
- Architecture: armhf
- Installed packages: memcached, php7.1-dev, build-essential,
  pkg-config, make, git, g++, gcc, libmemcached-dev, libmsgpack-dev,
  libmsgpackc2

PHP Version:

```
PHP 7.1.8-2+0~20170804100723.7+jessie~1.gbpae7f04 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2017 03:58:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.8-2+0~20170804100723.7+jessie~1.gbpae7f04, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

PHP Packages

```
libapache2-mod-php7.1
php-common
php7.1
php7.1-cli
php7.1-common
php7.1-curl
php7.1-dev
php7.1-gd
php7.1-imap
php7.1-json
php7.1-mbstring
php7.1-mcrypt
php7.1-mysql
php7.1-opcache
php7.1-readline
php7.1-xml
php7.1-xmlrpc
php7.1-zip
```

PHP Modules

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

My error summary

```
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Memcached::getByKey() with CAS [tests/experimental/get_bykey_cas.phpt]
Memcached::getDelayedByKey() with CAS [tests/experimental/getdelayed_bykey_cas.phpt]
Memcached::getDelayedByKey() with callback exception [tests/experimental/getdelayed_cbthrows.phpt]
Memcached::getMulti() bad server [tests/experimental/getmulti_badserver.phpt]
Memcached::getStats() [tests/experimental/stats.phpt]
Memcached::getStats() with bad server [tests/experimental/stats_badserver.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

I think I forgot to install a library or an PHP package. But I don`t know which one?

You need more informations? No problem I can post the completely Logfile.

I hope you can help me to fix that special problem.

Comment: Have anyone an idea to fix the problem?